# Solving equations such as $2\sin^2(x) - 2x\sin(x) + 1 = 0$, where $x$ appears both inside and outside the sine function

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone please help me in solving this equation where the variable in the sine function also occupies a place as the constant term in this trigonometric quadratic equation.

> Solve for $x$ such that:
> $$2\sin^2(x) - 2x\sin(x) + 1 = 0$$
> Where $x \in [0,\pi/2]$

Please help me on how to solve these type of equations, it would be a great favor.

Comment: Please provide an attempt. What are you stuck on? What do you not understand? We need to understand these things in order to help you.

Comment: Numerical methods

Comment: @FishDrowned I mean you cannot use the quadratic formula directly here, then how do you solve it ? + I want values of X in the range [0,pi/2] (I will edit this in the question)

Comment: @Andrei you mean hit and trial ??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: @Andrei Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

First of all, *Welcome to the site !*

I suppose that, graphing, you notice that the solution is quite close to $\frac \pi 2$.

So, let $x=\frac \pi 2-t$ and use small angle approximation. This would give you a very good approximation of the solution.